# Why does this say “attempt to call nil value”?

Tags: lua

This piece of code:

```lua
local emojis = { one = "", two = "", three = "", four = "", five = "", six = "", seven = "", eight = "", nine = "", zero = "↙️" }

code = "rnjzgrnjzgrnjzg↙️rnjzg↙️rnjzgrnjzg↙️rnjzgrnjzg↙️rnjzg↙️rnjzgrnjzg" 
code = code:gsub("rnjzg", "\\") 
code = code:gsub(emojis.one, "1") 
code = code:gsub(emojis.two, "2") 
code = code:gsub(emojis.three, "3") 
code = code:gsub(emojis.four, "4") 
code = code:gsub(emojis.five, "5") 
code = code:gsub(emojis.six, "6") 
code = code:gsub(emojis.seven, "7") 
code = code:gsub(emojis.eight, "8") 
code = code:gsub(emojis.nine, "9") 
code = code:gsub(emojis.zero, "0") 
load(code)()
```

always results in “attempt to call nil value”, why is that?

Comment: Please format this in a readable manner. And explain what it's meant to do.

Comment: I just edited it, it’s meant to convert these emojis into numbers and the random string into a \, turning it into bytecode

Comment: It attempts to compile and run (using `load`) a string which isn't valid Lua code. Why do you think it should succeed?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-load) for `load` says this about its return values:

> If there are no syntactic errors, `load` returns the compiled chunk as a function; otherwise, it returns **fail** plus the error message.

("Fail" means `nil`.) If I insert this...

```
print(code)
print(load(code))
```

...between the `code` definition and the `load` call, I get this:

```
\112\114\105\110\116\40\39\104\105\39\41
nil     [string "\112\114\105\110\116\40\39\104\105\39\41"]:1: unexpected symbol near '\'
lua: ./lua.lua:19: attempt to call a nil value
stack traceback:
        ./lua.lua:19: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

So if you look at both return values, you can see if the string was valid Lua code before trying to call it. Try changing the `load` call to this:

```
local chunk <const>, err <const> = load(code)
if err then
  print(err)
else
  chunk()
end
```